# Facebook login in fragment

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I would like to use Facebook login in my App. I have just registred app and added SDK to project. However, I tried to follow the tutorial from documentation but nothing worked (I need to get ID and email from profile and send to to my server).

**Fragment**

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.ivLogo) ImageView ivLogo;
    @BindView(R.id.email) EditText edEmail;
    @BindView(R.id.password) EditText edPassword;
    @BindView(R.id.btnFbLogin) LoginButton btnFbLogin;

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    String email, password, ID;
    User user;

    public LoginFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static LoginFragment newInstance() {
        LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                        Log.i("success", "success");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login_screen, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        btnFbLogin.setReadPermissions("email");
        btnFbLogin.setFragment(this);

        // Callback registration
        btnFbLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

    private void FBcallback() {
        FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                        loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(
                                    JSONObject object,
                                    GraphResponse response) {

                                try {
                                    String email = object.getString("email");

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() { }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) { }
        };

        btnFbLogin.setReadPermissions("email");
        btnFbLogin.registerCallback(callbackManager, callback);
    }


    private void loginEmail() {
        FactoryAPI.getInstanceLogin().login("hardcoded mail", "hardcoded password").enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    user = response.body().getUser();
                    startActivity();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.email_password_is_not_right, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void loginFB() {
        FactoryAPI.getServieFBlogin().loginFB(email, ID).enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, Response<UserResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    user = response.body().getUser();
                    startActivity();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("error", "error");
            }
        });
    }

    public void getEmailPassword() {
        email = edEmail.getText().toString();
        password = edPassword.getText().toString();
        if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.empty_properties, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public static boolean emailValidation(CharSequence target) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
    }

    public void startActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AccountActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("account", user);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
    }

    @OnClick({R.id.sign_up_email, R.id.btnFbLogin})
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.sign_up_email:
                loginEmail();
            case R.id.btnFbLogin:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void getProfile(Profile profile){
        if(profile != null){
            ID = profile.getId();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error?

Comment: it must be in the fragment. Facebook SDK is not as clear as I expected

Answer (score 2):

As your facebook login is in Fragment not in activity, so the
callback comes in onActivityResult() of Activity in which this fragment attached.

You can check this after override the onActivityResult() of your activity, and put a debug point there.

After you getting result in your activity onActivityResult() method, you can send it to your fragment's onActivityResult().

Hope this will help.

Comment: Is there any sweet library which is worth using to handle facebook login?

Comment: No need for any library, you will find everything in facebook documentation, just in case of fragment you need to check for the callback as I mentioned above.

Comment: I have done already, but I need a user's email (I have added permissions) but it does not work - it sends only name and ID. (I use Graph request)

Comment: If you add 'email' permission then it will give you user email, but not in every case. As per the facebook documentation "Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty."

Comment: 2 years later, but once fired the `onActivityResult` in the Main Activity, the `onActivityResult` in the fragment will be fired inmediately so is not needed to send from activity to fragment, because it is made automatically.

Answer (score 2):

First of all if you are using LoginButton then you don't need to register with LoginManager. Here is the sample

//Using Facebook's LoginButton

//Register Callback
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email")); //set permissions as public_profile, email, etc
loginButton.setFragment(this);    //If you are using in a fragment

// Callback registration
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        // App code
    }
});
```

Now with LoginManager when using Custom Button to login instead of FB's LoginButton

```
//To check if you are already logged In
  boolean loggedIn = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null;


// To Manually login. This will launch facebook's login screen.
 LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, 
 Arrays.asList("public_profile","email"));
```

In both the cases, for Fragment or Activity you need to handle onActivityResult

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Copy/Paste from Facebook for Developers.